# How many scrolls do user take on news application?

Tags: infinite-scroll

I need to set criteria on showing ads on my app, so i was wandering, how many scrolls do user take on news application?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for everyone but I'll keep scrolling as long as:

- I have time
- I expect something interesting will show up
- I am not bombarded with ads

It's hard to pinpoint a threshold but if you have an ongoing list of articles I'd be frustrated if more than 1 in 10 was an ad placement.

However I'd argue that the news list is likely a bad spot to place ads. The user is trying to quickly scan a list for something they do want to read more about (e.g. Very little attention/time) placing the ad on the full article page would be better because they have already chosen that article to be of interest and (hopefully) they read it all... Thus there is more "impression" time for the ad to sit there and try to peak the users interest.